# How can I use a size parameter for datatype definitions

Tags: isabelle

I want to use the `word` type from "HOL-Library.Word" in a `datatype` where I don't want to fix the size of the `word`.

```
datatype 's Foo = Foo1 "'s word" | Foo2 "'s word"
```

But this does not work, Isabelle complains with

> Type definition with open dependencies, use "typedef (overloaded)" or enable configuration option "typedef_overloaded" in the context. 
> Type:  's Foo.Foo_IITN_Foo 
> Deps:  len_of('s) 
> The error(s) above occurred in typedef "Foo.Foo_IITN_Foo"

If it was a `record`, I could use `overloaded` like this

```
record(overloaded) 's Bar =
  bar1 :: "'s word"
```

But if I try to use `overloaded` for a `datatype`

```
datatype(overloaded) 's Foo = Foo1 "'s word" | Foo2 "'s word"
```

Then I get the error

> Outer syntax error⌂: type variable expected, 
> but keyword overloaded⌂ was found

How can I define a `datatype` that uses `word` of a size that is not fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the details of `typedef_overloaded`, but it does appear in the AFP, so the following should be okay:

```
context notes [[typedef_overloaded]] begin
datatype 's Foo = Foo1 "'s::len word" | Foo2 "'s word"
end
```

Or, if you prefer not using it, want to be extra safe, just create a bnf without the word and create new abbreviation that work only with words...

```
datatype 's Foo_tmp = Foo1_tmp 's  | Foo2_tmp 's 

type_synonym 's Foo = "'s word Foo_tmp"
abbreviation Foo1 :: ‹_ ⇒ 's word Foo_tmp›where
"Foo1 ≡ Foo1_tmp"
abbreviation Foo2 :: ‹_ ⇒ 's word Foo_tmp›where
"Foo2 ≡ Foo2_tmp"
```